# JTable reload data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, reload

I have the following JTable in code:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Category", "Seller", "Sell Price", "Current Bid", "End Date", "Open"};
Object[][] data = GetAuctionTableData();
final JTable AuctionTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

I also have a Button on the form and wish to reload the data into the table on the click of the button. How do I do this? Do I need to use a AbstractTableModel?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the button:

```
    RefreshAuctionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object[][] data = GetAuctionTableData();
        AuctionTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    }});
```

This code does not work as the JTable is declared as final. I currently have it as final because it is accessed from inner classes (buttons, as above).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Use common Java case conventions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want the button to change about the table.

- If the button just triggers updates in the objects within `data`,
  then you only need to use `AuctionTable.update` (or something like that).
- If it triggers an insertion, then it would be useful to add just the
  row to be inserted directly to `AuctionTable`. Use
  `((DefaultTableModel) AuctionTable.getModel).addRow(...);`
- If it triggers a deletion, then you would need just the index of the
  row to be deleted. Use `((DefaultTableModel)
  AuctionTable.getModel).removeRow(...);`

Otherwise, I'll need more information about the button's action, or you can make a call to `GetAuctionTableData()` each time the button is pressed to reload the whole JTable's information (something that might not be desirable at all).

**EDIT**

To reload the whole contents while keeping the `final` modifier for `AuctionTable`, use the `setDataVector` method instead of re-setting the table in the button's action listener.

```java
RefreshAuctionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object[][] data = GetAuctionTableData();
        ((DefaultTableModel) AuctionTable.getModel()).setDataVector(data, columnNames);
    }
});
```

You'll have to set your `columnNames` to `final` as well, though.

Comment: I am wanting to reload the whole JTable's information. Can I do this if the JTable is final?

Comment: Yes, you can. The `final` keyword just prevents you to assign other object to the variable `AuctionTable`, which is what does not work in your current code. Just use the `DefaultTableModel`'s `setDataVector` method. Will update my answer with the code.

Comment: I am getting the following error: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
Am I correct in saying that I need to make the JTable of type DefaultTableModel?

Comment: Typo: `AuctionTable.getModel` should be `AuctionTable.getModel()`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I saw the typo, it has been fixed and the above error still occurs.

Comment: Hmmm… It works for me. Check the location of the parenthesis. `AuctionTable.getModel()` gets the model of the JTable, `(DefaultTableModel)` casts the model to the given class. From that, you can use the `setDataVector` method.

Comment: If that still does not work, then use `((DefaultTableModel) (AuctionTable.getModel()))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DefaultTableModel and use addRow(Object[] rowData) to set the data.You can notify the data changes by model.fireTableDataChanged();

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` fires the correct events implicitly; you shouldn't have to do so explicitly.